# ncurses: prints out a seemingly random string

Tags: c, linux, ncurses, read-eval-print-loop

Am using ncurses to build a simple REPL, and each time I run the executable, it appends a bogus string, and I can't seem to figure out what's going on. One thought is my use `strcat` to generate the prompt that's intended to be similar to what's in e.g. zsh, bash, etc: `(user) @ wsh (% or #)`. Here are a few example outputs.

```
h';�^?
mmmeeeker @ wsh  h';�^?
mmmeeeker @ wsh  h';�^?
mmmeeeker @ wsh  h';�^?
mmmeeeker @ wsh  h';�^?
mmmeeeker @ wsh  h';�^?
mmmeeeker @ wsh  h';�^?
mmmeeeker @ wsh  h';�^?
mmmeeeker @ wsh  h';�^?
mmmeeeker @ wsh  h';�^?
mmmeeeker @ wsh
```

Without changing anything in my code,

```
~@߳~]^?
mmmeeeker @ wsh  ~@߳~]^?
mmmeeeker @ wsh  ~@߳~]^?
mmmeeeker @ wsh  ~@߳~]^?
mmmeeeker @ wsh  ~@߳~]^?
mmmeeeker @ wsh  ~@߳~]^?
mmmeeeker @ wsh  ~@߳~]^?
mmmeeeker @ wsh
```

and so on, ad infinitum. Most everything is commented out except for the REPL to try to isolate this. Here's the code I've got currently kept to a minimum:

sh.c, which contains the driving function

```c
// includes etc
int main(argc, **argv) {
  WINDOW *w = initscr();
  noecho();
  keypad(stdscr, 1);

  int ret = wsh_main(argc, 
argv, w);
  delwin(w);
  endwin();
  return 0;
}
```

and the wsh_main function, again, mostly commented out.

```c
...
int wsh_main (int argc, int **argv, WINDOW *w) {
  
  // as an aside, surely there's a better way to form this string/ concatenate several at once? I couldn't find one.
  char* t;
  char* uid;
  char host[HOST_MAX+1];
  // gethostname() things, with error check

  char bang[BANG_MAX]; // BANG_MAX is currently 64
  strcat(bang, '\n');
  strcat(bang, uid);
  strcat(bang,  " @ wsh");
  // conditionals to add # or % appropriately
  // also used strcat for this

  //... large block of commented out things for init
  // ...

  char buf[BUFF_SIZE];
  char *tokens[TOKS * sizeof(char *)];
  char *args[TOKS * sizeof(char *)]; // these were fine while I was still using stdout

  for (;;) {
    if (wprintw(bang, w) == ERR) {
      refresh();
      perror("err msg");
      return -1;
    }
    refresh();

   // memset to 0 for buf, tokens, args as appropriate
   // as well as a few other things I consider irrelevant to this.

   char in;
   int i = 0; // I suppose I could just have been iterating with the pointer 
              // to beginning of buf instead

    for (;;) {
      // commented out except for capturing EOL.
      // this is what contains the logic for e.g. adding to buffer, deleting, 
      // arrow keys, Tab, etc.
    }
  }
}
...
```

As I mention, I believe the culprit to be the rather scuffed `strcat` calls, but messing around with those + the `BANG_MAX` has been fruitless.

Comment: You need to initialise bang before you start appending to it. Always remember that in C local variables are not initialised automatically.

Comment: And you can't `strcat` a character. Your compiler should warn you about that. In C, chars are small integers; strcat expects a pointer to a NUL-terminated array of characters, aka "string". Anyway, you should use `snprintf`: simpler, safer, and usually faster.